# Errors for $\mathsf{LWE}$

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, lwe, gaussian-noise

Why do we take Gaussian-like errors in $\mathsf{LWE}$?

Why for example we don't take uniform errors?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few main reasons we use Gaussians for errors:

- It makes tight security proofs easier, or at least most hardness proofs rely on the error distribution being Gaussian.
- They produce small vectors that closely approximate a uniform error distribution for any lattice (see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/discrete-gaussian-sampling-role-in-lattice-based-crypto))

There are problems with true Gaussian distributions, mainly that they can't be sampled very efficiently. This is why we tend to use 'Gaussian-like' distributions as you put it.

Comment: it is worth mentioning that "true gaussians" here should be read as true *discrete* gaussians. It is actually extremely efficient to sample true *continuous* gaussians, say using the [Box Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform). One can then [round them](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1025) to get a distribution close to a discrete gaussian that often suffices. Note that one does lose something in doing this though --- you need higher precision sampling. This is quantified on page 37 of the linked paper.